# Need help in styling a tag

Tags: css

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Technology-BBC News
  </title>
  <style>
    body {
      margin: 0;
      font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    }
    
    #topbar {
      width: 1265px;
      margin: 0 auto;
      height: 40px;
      background-color: #FFFFFF;
    }
    
    #logo {
      margin-top: 8px;
      width: 85px;
      float: left;
      margin-right: 15px;
    }
    
    .topbar-section {
      float: left;
      border-left: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
      height: 100%;
    }
    
    #signin-img {
      width: 22px;
      margin-top: 11px;
      margin-left: 11px;
      float: left;
    }
    
    #signin-text {
      /* margin-top: 100px; */
      position: relative;
      top: 10px;
      left: 8px;
      font-weight: 600;
      font-size: 13px;
      padding-right: 50px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="topbar">
    <img id="logo" src="images/BBC_logo.png" alt="logo">
    <div id="singin" class="topbar-section">
      <img id="signin-img" src="images/signin.png" alt="">
      <span id="signin-text"> Sign in</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  -
</body>

</html>
```

here I am trying to give margin to `#signin-text` but it's not working ... I used positioning that worked but margin-top didn't can someone please tell me why the margin-top property in `#signin-text` not working this is my first question of stackoverflow please forgive if the question is asked in a wrong way. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`span` is an [inline element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Inline_elements). That's why it can't accept `margin`. If you change this ([change its block level](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Inline_elements#changing_element_levels)) by giving `display: inline-block` for example, the `margin` will affect.

```css
span {
  margin-top: 15px;
}

.inline-block {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>natural</span>
</div>
<div>
  <span class="inline-block">inline-block</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using css property `top` with `margin-top` it will not work.`top` always takes precedence over `margin-top` when using with `position` property. Check https://www.w3schools.com/Css/css_positioning.asp for reference. Try using `top` with a value `100px`

Comment: margin-top will never gonna work on span element unless you specify it as inline-block or block element

Comment: Yup! You are right. I missed the `span` tag which is not a block element. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

spans are the inline elements that take margins horizontally only not vertically, Only the block and inline-blocks can take margins as vertically and horizontally.

> Margin properties specify the width of the margin area of a box. The
> 'margin' shorthand property sets the margin for all four sides while
> the other margin properties only set their respective side. These
> properties apply to all elements, but vertical margins will not have
> any effect on non-replaced inline elements.

there are many solutions to your problem, either use div or specify span tag as inline-block in your style tag. Still, there are many other ways to achieve this